# How long does it take for IIS to shut down after app_offline.htm is in place?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, app-offline.htm

I have a deployment workflow for an ASP.NET web app which begins with puttin an `app_offline.htm` file to the directory of my web app. Despite that, I usually get this error:

> The process cannot access the file ... because it is being used by
>   another process.

Indicating that the IIS process is still running despite the fact that the `app_offline.htm` file is in place. If I remote desktop to the server and do a manual `iisreset` or shut down IIS with its GUI (or just wait a few minutes after manually putting the `app_offline.htm` file there, then the workflow works correctly.

So, how long does it take for IIS to shut down after `app_offline.htm` is in place?

Comment: I ran across same issue with MVC app. This may be helpful or provide some guide: http://blog.kurtschindler.net/post/more-app_offlinehtm-woes

Comment: @bdoshi - Unfortunately that article deals with a completely different issue.

Answer (score 3):

The default is (up to) 90 seconds. This is defined in the application pool settings that your web application is running under in IIS as "Shutdown Time Limit".

[Process Model documentation at Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add/processModel)
[image]

Comment: That's the answer that helped me to solve the "file locked" issues when automating deployments to IIS using powershell. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know but I would like to know. So I ran some tests...

The effect is pretty much immediate, but it may take some time for the IIS app to actually shut down due to extra clean up code. Expect files to be locked for some time even after `app_offline.htm` is in effect.

The actual file system event information takes just a few milliseconds to propagate.

[image: procmon]

Comment: > *Expect files to be locked for some time even after app_offline.htm is in effect.*
Yes, but **how much** time?

Comment: @Venemo it's impossible to tell and you should understand this. Here's what you can do, you can poll the IIS web site for status, you can try to move and delete files and handle the resource sharing violations that might occur but you cannot arrive at an exact answer because it depends on stuff that it impossible to know for sure. Have you tried actually querying the IIS APIs that exist for managing the IIS infrastructure? What does MSDeploy do?

Comment: You might notice that this is a 4 year old question. I no longer work at the company where I needed to deal with this. So, unfortunately, I cannot try your suggestions.

Comment: If your answer is *"It's impossible to tell"*, that's okay and I will accept that answer if you provide a reliable source of this information. :)

Comment: @Venemo I just told you, and I also told you why. If there's a gap in your knowledge please ask more questions so that I can fill them in ;)

Comment: @John Liedegren - Thanks for this answer.  We are currently deploying with Azure Pipeline and I do iisreset /stop before deployment then iisreset /start after deployment is done.  I was thinking of changing to use app_offline.htm but now it looks like that's a very bad idea since files may still be locked.  The iisreset is working perfectly, only disadvantage is it affects all apps in IIS.